# How to use keywords connecting Microsoft To Do with OneNote

Tags: office365, onenote, taskmanager

Is there a way to create OneNote keywords that:

(1) could just be typed, without using the OneNote tags; and
(2) could be synced with Microsoft To Do?

I want to find ways to create a convenient link between MS To-Do and OneNote.

Note that using links is very precarious. The link seems to crash whenever the OneNote page is moved. OneNote's page links are file paths within the note and seem to break as soon as you change the folder.

**OneNote Tags wouldn't be a solution** because MS To Do can't understand it.

I tried to **create manually written keywords**: like Twitter/Evernote hashtags. The problem is that OneNote search can't find special characters when you input them on its Search box.

Some observations about OneNote search:

**(1) It cannot search for exact phrases**:

As is usual in search engines, a search for `foo bar` returns any page that has both `foo` and `bar` in it.

Searching `foo bar` returns:

```
foo <- not shown 
bar <- not shown
foo bar <- shown
foo     bar <- shown
foo
bar (with line break) <- shown
```

A search for `"foo bar"` with the quotation marks is ignored by OneNote, and thus you return the same results:

```
foo <- not shown 
bar <- not shown
foo bar <- shown
foo     bar <- shown
foo
bar (with line break) <- shown
```

**(2) OneNote's support for standard search operators is poor, if it has any at all**

Trying to search for `foo OR bar` looking for pages that would contain either one word or the other will actually return pages that contain all three words (`food`, `or` and `bar`).

*About special signs*: OneNote's search ignores just about everything that might be used to make a string of text more unique.
For example, searching for the keyword `wiki` with:

`#Wiki`
`@Wiki`
`!Wiki`
`:Wiki`
`;Wiki`
`>Wiki`
`&Wiki`
`+Wiki`
`=Wiki`

Will return the same results as if no sign was used in front of the word `wiki`.

Finally, a search for `id:Wiki` returns:

```
id:Wiki
id Wiki
id: Wiki
id :Wiki
id Wiki
id 
Wiki (with line break)
```

Since my job, my university and my family all use Microsoft Office, my cloud services are all OneDrive, so changing the note taking app is **not** an option (I use it with tons of GB attached as files)...

Comment: Do you use Outlook? It's not as eloquent a solution as I think you're looking for, but you can create Outlook tasks in OneNote, and Outlook tasks sync with To Do.

Comment: Outlook tasks in OneNote?